# What are some tests of local Lorentz invariance?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

I've seen this phrase mentioned in places other than this quote from a [paper](https://hyperspace.uni-frankfurt.de/2014/06/12/living-reviews-in-relativity-the-confrontation-between-general-relativity-and-experiment/):

> Einstein’s equivalence principle (EEP) is well supported by
> experiments such as the Eötvös experiment, tests of local Lorentz
> invariance and clock experiments.

Could someone please reference one of these "tests of local Lorentz Invariance"?  One of the critical features of Lorentz Invariance, as I understand it, is the constancy of the speed of light.  This troubles me, because we know that there are many, many galaxies travelling superluminally, so there must be some scale at which Lorentz Invariance fails.  How sensitive are these tests Lorentz Invariance?

The reason I ask is this: in the fourteenth century, Tyco Brahe reasoned that if the Earth revolved around the Sun, then we would detect parallax with the distant stars.  Our best instruments at the time detected no parallax between solstices, therefore we had overwhelming evidence the Earth was stationary.  So, what I'm asking is: Do we have better evidence of Lorentz Invariance than Brahe had of Earth's immobility?

Comment: To me, “tests of local Lorentz invariance” just means tests of Special Relativity. Machines like the Large Hadron Collider would not even *work* if SR were not valid, nor would they be confirming a relativistic quantum field theory *with a Lorentz-invariant action*. I know from previous questions and comments that you are a skeptic about some parts of mainstream physics, but are you now doubting its very foundation?

Comment: *but are you now doubting its very foundation?*  Yes, I am.  Where I come from, this is called **critical thinking skills**.  If this is offensive to the sensibilities of the board, please let me know and I'll take my questions elsewhere.  I've got a metric that works better than FLRW/GR at predicting the magnitude of SNe Ia, however, this metric violates Lorentzian Invariance, so I've got a reason to question whether your foundations are solid or not.

Comment: I believe that you have been a member of PSE long enough to realize that this site deals exclusively with mainstream physics. In fact, being non-mainstream is an explicit *closure reason* for questions here. If you wish to promote non-mainstream physics, then this is the wrong place for you.

Comment: I am sincerely sorry the suggestion of critically thinking about your assumptions is so uncomfortable for you.  Are you aware that **progress in science is made one funeral at a time?**  Have you ever thought about the kind of scientist Plank was thinking about when he said that?  At what point did examining our assumptions become 'non-mainstream' for you?

Comment: I am not interested in arguing with you regarding the policies of this site. Despite the non-mainstream views expressed in your comments, I don’t consider your question to be non-mainstream. Hopefully you will get a good answer... such a good one that you will be 100% convinced that SR is correct. Obviously my comment did not achieve that.

Comment: *Are you aware...* Indeed I am. I have been hearing the quote “progress in science is made one funeral at a time” from relativity denialists for about 50 years.

Comment: *Obviously my comment did not achieve that*  Your answer did not address my question: we know that many galaxies travel faster than light.  This violates Lorentz Invariance.  We know that at a point, the geometry of spacetime is Lorentzian.  I'm asking, what proof do you have that the physics in your laboratory are closer to the physics of a point than the physics of a galaxy?